# UIPrintInteractionController's printToPrinter crash in 'lookupLastUsedPrinter' API call

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios15, airprint

- We are seeing following crash in our codebase (iOS 15) with following call stack in UIPrintInteractionController.
- Could anyone please help with your inputs on how we can address following "UIPrintInteractionController's printToPrinter api crash"

### Crash stack

```
uncaught ObjC exception, reason: -[PKPrinter _internalPrinter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 

Last Exception Backtrace:
2   libobjc.A.dylib                      objc_exception_throw (??:0)w + 60 
3   CoreFoundation                       __CFOAInitializeNSObject (??:0)3 + 1535940 
4   CoreFoundation                       ___forwarding___ (??:0)3 + 188056 
5   CoreFoundation                       __CFRunLoopDoTimers (??:0)0 + 96 
6   UIKitCore                            __51-[UIPrintPanelViewController lookupLastUsedPrinter]_block_invoke (??:0)5 + 15751960 
7   UIKitCore                            -[UIPrintPanelViewController loadView] (??:0)5 + 15735732 
8   UIKitCore                            __88-[UIPrintInteractionController _generatePDFInRange:useFullRange:withQuality:completion:]_block_invoke (??:0)5 + 15935408 
9   UIKitCore                            -[UIPrintInteractionController printToPrinter:completionHandler:] (??:0)5 + 15915992 
10  UIKitCore                            -[UIPrintInteractionController _completePrintPageWithError:] (??:0)5 + 15960488 
11  UIKitCore                            -[UIPrintInteractionController printToPrinter:completionHandler:] (??:0)5 + 15915780
```

### Codebase that resulted above crash

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printControllerT, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
  [printControllerT setDelegate:nil];                          
};
[printController setDelegate:printDelegate];
[printController setPrintingItem:rurlPrintJob];                    
[printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

### More info

- meanwhile I have found one apple thread where its mentioned that “App Crash when using print of UIPrintInteractionController” ==>https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/689876.
- Above thread suggested to use printer.contactPrinter instead of printerController.print.Since our current codebase used default iOS codepath(printToPrinter) with ‘[[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController]presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler]]’ api call , I am not able to apply this suggestion in current codebase.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an internal iOS issue. `PKPrinter` is a private class, but `_iternalPrinter` is a private selector from the public class `UIPrinter`. Something got messy under the hood.

There is a workaround. Try setting fresh `UIPrintInfo` before presenting print UI:

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printControllerT, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
  printController.delegate = nil;                          
};
printController.delegate = printDelegate;
printController.printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo]; // <- Fixes the crash
printController.printingItem = rurlPrintJob;
[printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

We are observing this crash for a while and finally were able to reproduce it. In our case, we have two different code locations using `UIPrintInteractionController`. First of them assigns `UIPrintInfo` with various adjustments, like job name and output type. The second place simply sets `printingItem` and presents UI, just like in your sample code. But print attempts are not isolated, and it looks like some internals are getting corrupted in some scenarios.